# cant set up Germany localization in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

What i am doing wrong ?
create folder in **/www/app/i18n/vendor/de_de/** with this fildes:

```
--composer.json
--de_de.csv
--language.xml
--registration.php
```

**composer.json:**

```
{
    "name": "vendor/de_de"
    ,"type": "magento2-language"
    ,"description": "Germany language"
    ,"authors": [{
        "name": "John",
        "email": "xxx@xxx.com",
        "role": "Developer"
    }]  
    ,"extra": {"map": [["*", "vendor/de_de"]]}
}
```

**language.xml:**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<language xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='urn:magento:framework:App/Language/package.xsd'>
    <code>de_DE</code>
    <vendor>vendor</vendor>
    <package>de_de</package>
</language>
```

**registration.php:**

```
<?php

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::LANGUAGE,
   'vendor_de_de',
   __DIR__
);
```

after when this files created i run this commands:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases -o app/i18n/vendor/de_de/de_de.csv -m
php bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/vendor/de_de/de_de.csv de_DE
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy de_DE
```

but site still on English, please tell me why ?

Answer (score 0):

After this process you need to select locale from Admin > Stores > Configuration > General. Change locale and then run deploy command and clear cache.
Now you can see your changes made in translation csv.